# Передачи имени переменной в функцию

Tags: python

Есть код функции, которая по значению в списке находит имя переменной для отображения на чертеже Компас и функция иногда дает ошибку.

Вот если бы передать в функцию имя переменной в текстовом виде, его можно отобразить, а затем найти значение переменной?

```
def tochka_imj(a,nomer):
    x=a.real
    y=a.imag

    def bar(var):
        for k, v in globals().items():
            if id(var) == id(a):
                if a==v:  
                     rez=k
        return rez
    rez= bar (a)
    iDocument2D.ksPoint(x, y, nomer)
    tekst (a+7+22*1j,rez)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сбой работы происходит если пытаться найти рассчитанную переменную, просто отсутствует в списке.

Если произвести операции с рассчитанной переменной, может появиться в списке. Теоретически также может быть несколько одинаковых значений, что также нужно учитывать.

Если передавать в функцию только имя, при попытке вызвать переменную, в функции она там отсутствует, придется включать `global`. Простое решение наверное отсутствует.

Пока при переменной после расчетов передаю имя переменной и ее значение:

```
tochka_imj_tz("a",a,nomer)
```

Comment: Вы не обрабатываете случай, когда функция bar ничего не найдет. Возвращайте в этом случае к примеру none. А потом обрабатывайте это ниже

Comment: @Vitaly Lysanov, а почему просто не передавать значение? Не вижу смысла в ваших манипуляциях с globals.

Comment: Чтобы нарисовать точку с наименованием (именем переменной),

Comment: Чтобы нарисовать точку с наименованием (именем переменной), нужно значение и имя, поэтому для надежности так и поступаю, дублирую в виде текста и значения. Если передать только текст, а затем через eval пробовать получить значение, отказывается т.к. значение не передано в функцию. И поэтому можно пробовать через eval global имя, затем eval имя. Получается сложно.

Comment: @VitalyLysanov, передавайте имя и значение. Еще можно завести отдельный словарь (dict) специально для ваших точек, а не брать из globals.

Comment: @insolor спасибо, так и будем делать.